# Drive Quickstart NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

i'm trying to get the Google Drive Quickstart example to run but i'll always get a RuntimeException. This seems to come from the depths of the the API i use.

Does anyone had the same Problems then i and could help me to fix it?
Here is my errorcode.

> ```
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2016
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:100)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:269)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:408)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at com.example.drivequickstart.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:97)
> 12-20 19:19:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
> 12-20 19:19:55.100: D/OpenGLRenderer(15682): Flushing caches (mode 0)
> 12-20 19:19:55.130: D/OpenGLRenderer(15682): Flushing caches (mode 1)
> 12-20 19:20:19.750: I/Process(15682): Sending signal. PID: 15682 SIG: 9
> ```

I copied the code from the Drive Quickstarttutorial, here is a 
[link](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)

Comment: Look at here, someone has the same bug: https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/DeVd1BcWDn2 (this is the G+ Account of a Google Dev), the solution seems to be in the package name configured on my Google API console. Unfortunately I have exactly the same error than you, and I am sure the package name I use is the same than the one configured on my Google API console and I continue to get this error :-(

Comment: So know i had checked the my API Console settings, they seem to be right. Maybe someone else has an idea what we do wrong?

Comment: Fussel, which IDE are you using? I am under Intellij idea 12

Comment: I have just tried with Eclipse, new package name, new project in the API console, same error...

Comment: pommedeterresautee: I'm using Eclipse and bind the Drive API through the Google plugin for Eclipse, just like in the Videoexample. I think it should be the latest version of the API, I use v2. I have checked the package name; copy and paste to the API Console; maybe a problem with my SHA1 key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that the [initial resumable upload request](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable) is failing, probably because of failed authorization, and that is causing the NullPointerException.

Make sure you are using the latest version of the client library and double check your credentials in the APIs Console, package name and SHA1 fingerprint.

If that still doesn't work, try following the step-by-step video that goes through the setup of the same quickstart application: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ied1CjJ0iP0

Comment: The video says exatly the same thing that the text version.

Comment: I din't check the Drive API, i just checked the Drive SDK. Now it works. Thanks for all the help.